# Textview background not showing in gridview

Tags: android, textview, android-gridview

In my app I am using a gridview. In my adapter I have to show the last item with just a textview and a background.
I am resizing my grid item height in my adapter.

My Adapter class is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.hj.app.R;


public class AddToCollectionsGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Collections> objects;

Context mContext;

int itemHeight;

/**
 * 
 */
public AddToCollectionsGridAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<Collections> objects) {
    this.mContext = context;
    // this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // return objects != null ? objects.size() + 1 : 1;
    return 5;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    /*
     * return (position <= objects.size() - 1) ? objects.get(position) :
     * position;
     */return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.hj_collection_grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            itemHeight);
    holder.parentLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    if (position == 4) {
        holder.collectionImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.collectionNameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.newCollectionText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.newCollectionText
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hj_new_collection_bg);
    } else {
        holder.collectionImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.collectionNameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.newCollectionText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.newCollectionText.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    public FrameLayout parentLayout;
    public TextView newCollectionText;
    public ImageView collectionImage;
    public LinearLayout collectionNameLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        newCollectionText = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.add_new_collection_textView);
        collectionImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hj_grid_image);
        collectionNameLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.collection_name_layout);
        parentLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hj_grid_parent);
    }
}

/**
 * @param i
 */
public void setItemHeight(int itemHeight) {
    this.itemHeight = itemHeight;
}

    }
```

My Layout class for each grid item is

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/hj_grid_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hj_grid_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/houzz1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/collection_name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/hj_blurr_bg"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/hj_margin_medium"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/hj_margin_medium" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hj_grid_title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Umesh"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/hj_font_small" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hj_grid_price_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rs. 250"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/hj_font_small" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/add_new_collection_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hj_new_collection_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hj_new_collection_text"
    android:textColor="@color/hj_grey_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/hj_font_medium" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

Everything works fine. For my last element I wish to show the textview "add_new_collection_textView" . It is visible as per condition but the problem I am facing is that textview background is not visible.

Please Help!!!!!

Edit1:

hj_new_collection_bg

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hj_new_collection_pressed_bg" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hj_new_collection_pressed_bg" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hj_new_collection_normal_bg"></item>
</selector>
```

hj_new_collection_pressed_bg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#9E9E9E" />

<solid android:color="#9E9E9E" />
```

hj_new_collection_normal_bg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#9E9E9E" />

<solid android:color="#BDBDBD" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the @drawable/hj_new_collection_bg. So post that file.
Is it a image or a xml file. 
Also tell the expected color you want as a background.